# Is a normal distribution a distribution of one random variable or of multiple random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

In my Statistics class, we are sometimes given problems where we are told that a random variable $X$ has a normal distribution, *e.g.*, $X\sim N(-2,4)$. On other occasions, however, we are told that a *random sample* has a normal distribution, in language like the following: "Suppose that a random sample $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is from a $N(0,θ)$ distribution."

So, basically, I am confused about what a normal distribution *is*. Why in some contexts is a single random variable said to have a normal distribution, but in other contexts a random sample (several random variables) is said to be from a normal distribution? I feel like there's something basic I'm not grasping.

Comment: Sampling usually means independent variables with the same underlying distribution. This specifies the distribution of the random vector $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n).$ If you want sampling with some correlation, you may need to specify a "model" (e.g. time series $X_t = f(X_{t-1},\xi_t)$) or a multivariate dispersion matrix (e.g. $(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \sim \mathsf{N}(\mu, \Sigma),$ with $\Sigma$ tridiagonal, say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of sloppy language. When one says that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are sampled from a normal distribution, it is shorthand for saying that the random vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ has independent entries, each of which is drawn from the normal distribution. This is equivalent to saying that the random vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is drawn from a multivariate normal distribution with diagonal covariance matrix.

So to summarize: the normal distribution involves only one variable. A sequence of independent samples from a normal distribution involves several variables. Grouping them together gives a single sample from a multivariate normal distribution. In general one must specify the joint distribution of random variables in order to have a well-defined problem, but people are sloppy and when they leave it unspecified it is to be assumed that the random variables are jointly independent.